# VBA excel get request run-time error 70

Tags: excel, vba, request

Я пытаюсь использовать MSXML2 для того, чтобы получить код страницы. С любым сайтом, чей домен .com все получается, но домен .ru выдает Run-time error '70': Permission Denied

[image: Ошибка]
Сам код:

```
    Public Sub Info()

    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim url As String
    Dim test As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    
    url = "https://www.youtube.ru"
    XMLReq.Open "GET", url, False
    With XMLReq
        .setRequestHeader "accept", "*/*"
        .setRequestHeader "user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub Info()

Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim url As String
Dim test As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

url = "https://www.ya.ru"
XMLReq.Open "GET", url, False
    With XMLReq
        .setRequestHeader "accept", "*/*"
        .setRequestHeader "user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
    End With
End Sub
```

Проблема в том, что MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 - это локальный объект, которому позарез необходимо, чтобы сайт был в числе доверенных (можно попробовать добавить в настройках Internet Explorer - не проверял). Сервер-side объект же на локальную безопасность клал.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina за ответ.
Решил проблему переписав

```
Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
```

как

```
Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
```

(Нашел на https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938194/xmlhttp-request-is-raising-an-access-denied-error)